# Is it okay to ask for detailed feedback even after I got an offer?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, feedback

Is it okay to ask the hiring manager for feedback on myself even if I have already got the offer? I just really want to know how I perform, especially compared to other candidates. Also, I believe the feedback might be helpful as it might identify my weakness, etc.

Comment: If you got an offer that means you were either the best candidate or the best one that hadn't turned them down.

Comment: The best thing you can do to get a feeling for your relative performance is to spend some time being the interviewer rather than the interviewee.  You'll see what your competition is like in short order.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My recommendation is no, don't do this.  Why?  You're sending the message that you're already looking ahead to your next job interview.  This will give them the impression that you don't plan to stick around very long, which is not what you want to do when you're starting a new job.

As a comment says, you were the best candidate for the job - at least who hasn't turned them down (yet).  Consider this confirmation that you interviewed well.

If you accept the job, then once you've started - within conversations about how they want you do your job - it is probably okay to ask if during the interview they noted particular strengths they want you to utilize or weaknesses they want you to work on.

Comment: I think it can also show a lack of confidence in yourself, or even that you were "putting on a show" for the interview and want to know how good the show was. If they made an offer, just accept that you were the best candidate and don't solicit feedback that could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score -1):

Play it cool. Dont appear so approval seeking. Instead wait for sometime and when you and your interviewer are in a good mood such as on a lunch out or happy hour or some company outing, you can broach the topic in a humourous way

Comment: Hi Jay, assuming you're answering within the context of someone who does land the job, you should expand your answer to explain how to broach the subject. Vague answers that don't explain why a solution is the best tend to attract downvotes on our site due to the nature of the topic. Please see [the Back It Up rule](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/255/98) for more details. Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess so :). Will read the back it up rule